# Catching server time is updating

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I'm getting the date from the server to be displayed to the user.

```
DataHora = DateTime.Now;
```

I need this time to be displayed, that it would fire and update itself to the user as if it were a clock until there is a new request in the bank and that date and time be updated again.

I can not get this date and time from the client side, because it risks the client changing the date and time of the computer and being different from the server.

Comment: you could use signalr to broadcast to clients when "there is new request in the bank" and then trigger javascript to manage controlling the ticking/countdown of a clock and resetting the clock's state if necessary. You may risk a very small difference between the time shown between the client and server. not sure how imperative it is to keep these 100% perfectly in sync. that may be much more challenging

Comment: @GregH Thanks for replying, So I did not use the signalr library, I'll study more about it. Could you tell me if I can trigger the timer in the javascript with `DateTime.Now`

Comment: well simply typing `DateTime.Now` isn't going to do what you want. you would use signalr to broadcast messages to the client when a certain event happens (new request in the bank) then on the client you can use javascript to do whatever you need to do (set a clock to a certain time, make it tick, remove the clock, whatever)

Comment: @GregH Do you have an example?

Comment: not on hand but there are plenty available if you look around. a quick google search turned up https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr-and-mvc